# Issues with camera reset using a script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to centre the camera on the object and then, if player clicks on button (which will be added later) or outside of the pop-up which will be triggered by clicking on object (camera movement is just a first step).

My idea was to store the very first position of the camera and transform it back again if mouse is clicking outside of any clickable objects, but looks like it's not working.

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 camoriginposition;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        camoriginposition = Camera.main.transform.position;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Rigidbody rb;
            if (rb = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
            {
                Vector3 obj = rb.transform.position - new Vector3(0, -3, 2);
                cam.transform.position = obj;
                Debug.Log("curr cam pos" + cam.transform.position);
            }
            else
            {
                cam.transform.position = camoriginposition;
                Debug.Log("It triggers!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the Debug.Log output, but looks like transform.position cannot be processed.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what behaviour you are meaning by "not working", but maybe It's because you are declaring `camoriginposition` on every `Update()`, which would be definitely not the desired behaviour. Whenever you tries to store your cam's origin position to **local** variable, it will be gone when the `Update()` scope ends, and will be initialized again with new `Update()` call.

You have to seperate `camoriginposition` from `Update()`, like:

```cs
private Vector3 camoriginposition;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
         ...
}
```

And, it seems like there are another problem. You are storing `camoriginposition` on every mouse click, but with your description, It seems like it should be stored when *the ray actually hits* the gameobject.

You should move `camoriginposition = Camera.main.transform.position;`

into

`if (rb = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())` block.